# How to create a store and retrieve information software?

Tags: html, vb6

I am trying to help a niece to make a thesis on programming a software that will be able to store and retrieve scanned pictures using a GUI where we can input some parameters like name, unique id number, address and the like. Also, it should enable us to fill in some forms and then later on, we can print it. I have a little background in programming as I have tried VB6 a decade ago and never again ever since. I know that all these are possible with VB6 but it is obsolete now and I know that there are a lot of programming softwares out there that are more powerful and up to date. Can someone give me an advice on where to start and what programming language I can use now?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that software like this has already been written, and that there are even multiple implementations floating around. So I'm not sure how it would be suitable as a thesis: what new contributions would you be making to the field? In what ways would your ideas be novel? Aside from that nitpick, this question is unfortunately too broad and opinion-based to be suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CodyGray thank you for your reply, I am also thinking of a software that is OS incompatibility proof. Something that has no issues running in any edition of windows 7, 8 or even XP since I am thinking of running it using a virtual machine so that multiple user can access and use the software at the same time.

Comment: they did not get into details but looks like they are trying to get into the basic part. Maybe when they know where to start and have it working, they will try to add some additional sauce to the program.

Comment: VMs do not confer "multi user access."  VB6 programs run on everything from Windows 95 to Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are familiar with the VB6 syntax, I would think VB.NET would be a good choice for you.  As a .NET language, it is fully featured and powerful.  You can get Visual Studio Express Edition, or now Visual Studio Community Edition, for free.  Check them out at https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-express/ and https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/

Comment: I disagree. A passing familiarity with VB 6 from a decade ago will probably not be terribly useful in learning VB.NET. The similarities between the two languages are superficial at best, so you will have a lot of relearning to do anyway. And if your recollection of the syntax is foggy at best, you might as well learn a new syntax while you're at it. Note that I'm not saying that VB.NET would be a *bad* choice, just that seeing it as the natural replacement for VB 6 is not necessarily reasonable.

Comment: @CodyGray thank you for your reply, I am also thinking of a software that is OS incompatibility proof. Something that has no issues running in any edition of windows 7, 8 or even XP since I am thinking of running it using a virtual machine so that multiple user can access and use the software at the same time.

Comment: The thing with VB.NET is that it is mostly compatible with VB6. I paste VBScript (untyped) or VB6 (typed) code into notepad, add brackets, add `Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices`, remove `set`, then compile with `"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe"`.

Comment: @Monica for OS compatibility. you could use VB.NET as suggested by this answer and just use [.NET Framework 4.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39257) which is still compatible with XP.

aside from VB.NET, you could also try C# which also uses the .NET framework and can be developed with Visual Studio.